# Get all cms pages with certain layout

Tags: magento-1.7, cms, widgets

Is there a way to get all pages with certain layout?

What I want to achieve is to print all pages that have layout named "page with left sidebar" for example.

I'm new in Magento (in php also :D) so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to filter the `cms/page` collection by `root_template`:

```
$cmsPageCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('cms/page_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('root_template', 'two_columns_left');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can all cms by cms/page collection

```
$cmsPages=Mage::getResourceModel('cms/page_collection')
foreach($cmsPages as $eachPage){
var_dump($eachPage)
}
```

get individuals page by

```
$cms = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load(cmspageindenfiername, 'identifier');
```